# Re-Render only a particular child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic-forms

I am building a dynamic form and as of now, my component hierarchy is as follows:-

```
App
  Caseform
    DynamicFormBuilder
      Context.Provider
        Patients
          Patient key = "patient_1"
            ComponentCreator key = "patient_1_1"
              Textbox
            ComponentCreator key = "patient_1_2"
              Textbox
            ComponentCreator key = "patient_1_3"
              Textbox
          Patient key = "patient_2"
            ComponentCreator key = "patient_2_1"
              Textbox
            ComponentCreator key = "patient_2_2"
              Textbox
            ComponentCreator key = "patient_2_3"
              Textbox
```

As of now, I have hardcoded JSON data in caseform but eventually, it will come from the fetch call. As soon as DynamicFormBuilder receives the caseform metadata, it creates states out of it.

I am maintaining state at caseform level even for its child. I thought of doing it that way because the requirement was to support patch save(send only changed data to the backend on save button press). If anybody knows of a better way of doing this, please let me know.

I am passing in a function using context API to child components so that they can update the state in DynamicFormBuiler.

The issue I am facing is that let's say even if the user edits one textbox, the whole Dynamic form gets rendered.

I have gone through a lot of answers on StackOverflow that advise on using the shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle method, but I am not able to figure out how I will use it here.

I am adding a link to the sandbox and in the console, you can see that if a user edits a field all the things are rendered again.

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-forked-uoi11?file=/src/App.js)

Expected Behavior:- What I am looking for is for example:- if user-edited only one textbox say in patient 1 then only that textbox gets re-rendered again

This is my first time using react. I apologize in advance if someone feels I have not done enough research, I have read through a lot of questions but still facing some challenges, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: React will not re-render something with a key unless the key changes so the key needs to somehow incorporate all properties that could cause a component to re-render

Comment: @apokryfos I am creating key for each component, still react is re-rendering them, is it because as i have a nested state?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap each component in the React.memo() HOC, this should prevent excessive rerenders.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

-Edit-

Yes it works with class components too.

e.g.

```
const MyComponent = React.memo(class extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <h1>TEST</h1>
  }
});
```

Comment: are you talking about pure components. I think i cannot use react.memo() as i am using class components.

Comment: Yes it works with class components too.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example